# Multilanguage website crawling issue (links like en/en/...)

Tags: sitemap, multilingual, web-crawler

I've created a [multilanguage website](http://www.agriandgolf.com) and I tried to generate a sitemap with a common [Sitemap Online Generator](http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/crawl.html).

Unfortunally it crawled links like "en/en/..." or "it/de/en/..." (that not exist and are not correct of course). I'm afraid that Google could do the same.

I read all about  tag (maybe the problem is there) and did lots of trying, but the resutl is always the same: lots of redundant links (en/apartments/en/apartments/torre)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!**

I wrote my problem to the sitemap generator webmaster. It was an error about its tool (it doesn't consider singular apices around base-tag's attribute).

I sent the sitemap to google and everything was ok.